# All struts2 tag's each attributes usage examples

Tags: struts2

I need to know how to use each and every attribute of Struts2 tags. I
have gone through all possible websites by searching via Google, But
no one has understandable explanation or examples of each and every
attributes of each struts2 tags.

for example: In "**optiontransferselect**" tag, for
**allowAddAllToRight** attribute I have no idea what String do I need to give for it.

[here is one of the site I refered...](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/docs/optiontransferselect.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to understand every single option, do two things:

1. Use every single option.
2. Read the source code.

When something is listed as "enable", it's almost always a true/false value, as it is in this case. Why it's listed as a string, not sure; either an issue with the annotation processor, or it was added and the type conversion was done manually, or...?

While I (sort of) understand the motivation for wanting to understand "each and every attribute" of each tag, IMO your time would be better spent learning more important framework details.

Comment: Thanks Now I have some what clear in what I need to do to know those. And I have searched for source code but I get nothing, do u mean those HTML rendered by those as source code?

Comment: ya I got it. Now I started to go through those. Its interesting to to see how they did.

Comment: At last I found that the documentation of optiontransferselect" tag, for allowAddAllToRight is wrong. As they gave it as " Enable Add All To Left button" instead of "Disable Add All To Left button". I found this by tracing this tag inside the source code of struts2. @Dave Newton suggested.

Comment: @Sathishkumar Er... Not sure how you arrived at this conclusion.

Comment: 1st I was confused by "Enable Add All To Left button". since I had it already enabled by default. So as you suggested I looked into source code to find out what string is required actually. I found that its just "true or false" string is required, as you said they used string for some reason to handle these "true or false". Later I used it in my code. I gave "false" so that it removed the button"allowAddAllToRight". so when relating it to the Description I came to this conclusion.

Comment: @SathishKumarkk The doc for `allowAddAllToRight` is "Enable Add All To Right button"; if it's `"true"` the button is there, if it's `"false"` it isn't. I've made a note to go over some of these (or just remove them, since nobody really uses them), but the documentation for the options is correct, if incomplete.

Comment: I accept. But for Beginner like me, it leads us to confusion. At last  I understood that this way of making us to get confused it for good. since by solving these confusions we get stronger in struts.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you will find them at anywhere as these attributes have been defined and provided based on generic needs and its quit possible that some one need few of them and some need others.

i even never used all of the tag properties and in most of the cases we end up using few as per our choice.

If you want to find what each and every property/ attribute making end effect best way is to create a demo `struts2` application pick up few tags go to struts2 tag reference page read there description and start playing with them and see how things are changing and check generated HTML code.

There is no other shot-cut for this.
But why you need to know all the properties? i am just curious

[Struts2 tag refrence](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/docs/tag-reference.html)

Comment: since I always 1st try know everything in depth or at least know things related to what ever I use. that is it... here in this question I mainly need to know what are those possible Strings can be written inside those double quotes of each attributes. see for the same above example for "allowAddAllToRight", they have Description like..."Enable Add All To Right button". But they did't gave any hint for what possible String should I need to use for it. nothing is clear.

Comment: have you tried them what they doing and what changes they are making to HTML? i already told you there is no shortcut to dive deep other than try yourself.that's said

Comment: ya I tried but I could not get any Idea what possible string that I need to give... still now I learn for few attributes by seeing their usage in many web tutorials. If an attribute which have not used in those tutorials, what shall i do for those.

Comment: each and every attribute is being associated with some property as struts2 underlying using `ftl` templates to render the tags syntax which means when your page will render your properties will be used to generate HTML as ultimately tags will be converted to HTML.Now either you can see those template as well implementing class to see precise behavior

Comment: by seeing those HTML I can only get idea of how those tags are replacing HTML code. But still I did not get what I need. since few of those attributes are well explained by their name itself but few like this"allowAddAllToRight". I cant even guess what I need to give for this attribute.